# CreateProcess, first parameter question

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create a process called `s2.exe`. However I'm having trouble figuring out what needs to be passed in as the first argument. I tried putting the name and location of where the process would be located but I get "Error 2 starting CC".  What exactly should go in the first parameter? (According to MSDN it is the path to the module.)

```
int main()
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION po;
    STARTUPINFO s;
    GetStartupInfo (&s);

    if(CreateProcess(L"c:/s2", NULL, NULL, NULL,
        false, 0, NULL, NULL, &s, &po) == FALSE)
    {
         printf("Error %d starting CC\n", GetLastError());
         return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value of `2` returned from `GetLastError()` indicates `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. You need to pass in `c:/s2.exe`, assuming that `s2.exe` is actually in the `c:\` drive.

Note that the MSDN documentation for the `lpApplicationName` parameter in [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) says:

> The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path. **This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed.**

---

Also note that `void main()` is not standard C++. However, `int main()` is standard C++, and allows you to return some kind of exit code. (I edited your code snippet to reflect that.)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says about the `lpApplicationName` of the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) function:

> This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

You need `L"c:\s2"` rather than `L"c:/s2"`.  Microsoft prefers backslashes in paths. Forward slashes are accepted in some contexts but are generally problematic in code.